# Vim - auto reload quickfix error file when it changes

Tags: vim

I have a file (errors.txt) containing a list of errors (code style issues), which I load into Vim quickfix (`:cf errors.txt`). errors.txt gets automatically updated by an external program (running independently of Vim) as I fix the errors. Is there a way to have Vim auto-refresh the quickfix list when errors.txt changes?

Note that I do not want to get Vim to update errors.txt. Another program does this and I do not want to call it from Vim. I just want Vim quickfix to monitor errors.txt for changes. Thanks!

Search tags: vim quickfix update reload refresh monitor file automatic update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a recent enough version of Vim (not sure which one, but if you run `vim --version`, you'll need to see `+timers`), you can set an asynchronous timer to check if the file has been modified, and run another `cfile errors.txt` to reload the quickfix window's contents. Here's a proof-of-concept (check [here](https://gist.github.com/AndrewRadev/cc68443ced6bdf3f684c35709505cf73) for a syntax-highlighted version):

```
" The filename used for the cfile
let s:cfile_filename = ''
" The last mtime of the filename
let s:cfile_mtime = -1

" Define a command that can be called like:
"
"   Cfile errors.txt
"
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Cfile call s:Cfile(<f-args>)

function! s:Cfile(filename)
  let s:cfile_filename = a:filename

  " Update every 200ms
  let timer = timer_start(200, function('s:UpdateCfile'), {'repeat': -1})
  " First "update" to actually load the qf window immediately
  call s:UpdateCfile(timer)
endfunction

function! s:UpdateCfile(timer_id)
  " Stop the timer if the file is deleted
  if s:cfile_filename == '' || !filereadable(s:cfile_filename)
    call timer_stop(a:timer_id)
    let s:cfile_filename = ''
    let s:cfile_mtime = -1

    return
  endif

  " Get file mtime
  let mtime = system('stat -c %Y '.shellescape(s:cfile_filename))

  " Load the file in the quickfix window if the mtime is newer than the last
  " recorded one
  if mtime > s:cfile_mtime
    exe 'cfile '.s:cfile_filename
    let s:cfile_mtime = mtime
  endif
endfunction
```

If you put that in your `.vimrc`, or in a separate file in `~/.vim/plugins/`, you'll get a `:Cfile` command you can use just like the "real" one, except this one will also monitor the file you gave it for changes every 200ms. It will stop auto-updating when the file is deleted.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure there's going to be edge cases you'd have to take care of, so I'd recommend you use this as a starting point, try to understand it (by using `:help` for any functions or commands you don't know about), and build something that fits your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had been looking into using timers to achieve this. I found [this webpage](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Timer_to_execute_commands_periodically) useful as it provides a "fake" timer for older versions of Vim (but it's not ideal) and mentions that version 8 has the "real" timer that your example uses, which looks much better. Unfortunately my office seems to use an older version of Vim that does not have timers...

Comment: Sorry I do not have the reputation to upvote your solution. But I may accept it if it wins!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a suggestion for my own question which will hopefully encourage some discussion here. I could use the client/server feature of Vim which will allow another process to tell Vim to update the Quickfix list. In this case, my background program can tell Vim whenever it updates errors.txt! Check out [this section](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_external_programs_asynchronously_under_Windows#Getting_results_back_into_Vim) for a kinda similar example. As you can see, the other program uses [--remote](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html) to tell Vim what to do.

Only trouble is the version of Vim used by my colleagues does not have +clientserver compiled... I was hoping for a more "out-of-the-box" solution...

Comment: Yeah, there really isn't much you could do out of the box. Maybe you could use the `CursorHold` autocommand to update the list when it's not active: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorHold. But that's also not ideal, since it would only trigger after you stop typing for a certain number of milliseconds.